# cp /some/directory/./ vs /some/directory/

Tags: cp, copying

What, if any, is the difference between the following?

```
cp -Ra /some/directory/./ /other/directory/
```

and

```
cp -Ra /some/directory/ /other/directory/
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference here - `/some/directory/./` simply resolves as `/some/directory/`